# Bootstrap add nav and nav-pills to my dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with twitter bootstrap. I created a simple dropdown menu, but when i inspect the code in chrome inspector, i see that the class `nav nav-pills` are added to the `<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">` element.

How can i delete these classes ?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-circle btn-default " href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Action
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
            <a id="saveButton" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-paste"></i> Save as </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i just created a jsfiddle and this doesn't happend

Comment: You must have some extra script that's adding the classes...

Comment: share js file you use

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpwmps2x/) with bootstrap using your code and nothing happends. You might wanna check your javascript code and event listeners because you might be adding these classes with javascript code by yourself.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn btn-circle btn-default " href="javascript:;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Action
        <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li>
            <a id="saveButton" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-paste"></i> Save as </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```